# How do I write a python script to pop up a notification within scheduled time?

Tags: python-3.9

Here's what I did. It's just about a reminder for a friend to be able to take his drugs on time.

```
import time
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

notify = ToastNotifier()
CurrentTime = 0
IconPath = "C:\\Users\\Hash\\Downloads\\Pill0.ico"

def alert(AlertHour, AlertMinute, AlertMessage):
    while True:
        CurrentTime = time.time()
        CurrentHour = CurrentTime // 3600 % 24
        CurrentMinu = CurrentTime // 60 % 60

        if (CurrentHour == AlertHour and CurrentMinu == AlertMinute):
            notify.show_toast("Drop Time!", AlertMessage, duration=120, icon_path=IconPath)

alert(21, 30, ">>>> E P I C I P R I N  5ML <<<<")
alert(17, 48, ">>>> seccE P I C I P R I N  5ML <<<<")

alert(9, 15, ">>>> P A T A N O L <<<<")
alert(21, 15, ">>>> P A T A N O L <<<<")

alert(9, 32, ">>>> E P I C I P R I N  5ML <<<<")
alert(15, 32, ">>>> E P I C I P R I N  5ML <<<<")
alert(21, 32, ">>>> E P I C I P R I N  5ML <<<<")
alert(3, 32, ">>>> E P I C I P R I N  5ML <<<<")

alert(9, 50, ">>>> E P I F E N A C <<<<")
alert(17, 50, ">>>> E P I F E N A C <<<<")
alert(1, 50, ">>>> E P I F E N A C <<<<")

alert(22, 00, ">>>> E P I C I P R I N  5G <<<<")
```

But it only runs the first alert method ignoring the rest even if their conditions are met.
Right now I'm stranded.
Any help please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once you run the first function, it gets into an infinite loop, therefore the python interpreter never gets to run the other calls. What you want to look into is threading. In a nutshell, threading allows you to run multiple processes simultaneously. Look into it
[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)